# Can we use Bellman Ford's algorithm for backward recursion

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, graph-algorithm, path-finding, shortest-path

Hi all i am stuck at one place that is there any choice that we can use bellman ford's algorithm to calculate shortest path by following backward recursion.
As to find shortest path bellman uses the following equation for forward recursion

for all i
d^l[u] = min[d^l-1[u],min{d^l-1[i]+cost(i,u)}].

so can we use any equation for backward recursion?

Thank you

Comment: Might be better at http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you elaborate? What do you mean by "use any equation for backward recursion?" What do you mean by "backward recursion" in this context?

Answer (score 0):

We can break the bottom-up bellman algorithm into multiple stages.

In the k-th stage, we can find the shortest path less than k edge. And  the answer of k-th stage is based on k - 1 stage. We can write it as a recursion equation:

```
# shortest(k, v) means the shortest path to v in the k-th stage
# for all u which has an edge point to v 
shortest(k, v) = min(shortest(k-1, v), shortest(k-1, u) + len(u, v))
```

u can be iterated efficiently if some preprocessing is done.

Then use memorization to record counted result. The time complexity is still O(VE), but space complexity is O(V^2), which is larger than bottom-up method.